# d3js - custom axis tick format - hexadecimal

Tags: d3.js

I have data in base 10 (decimal) format, and I need it displayed on the y-axis as hexadecimal (base 16).  If I convert the data first d3 can't give me a linear scaled axis.  Any ideas on how to go about this? I'd like to just call "toString(16)" somewhere, but I haven't figured out where to make it work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `axis.tickFormat()` for your axis. The parameter is a format string, and hexadecimal is an `"x"` or and `"X"` depending on whether you want lowercase or uppercase letters.

Here's the documentation on [`axis.tickFormat()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat) and here's the information on [format strings](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#d3_format).

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfect.  I thought I'd tried that, but I was typing things out wrong.  the syntax that works is "your axis name".tickFormat(d3.format("x"));